# kotlin jvm string templating using json content

Tags: json, kotlin

How to implementation in Kotlin(1.3 X) JVM String templating using Json content ?. I see lot of implementation in Java using Jackson and Velocity, Here I am looking for Kotlin based solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you might use just raw string like this:

```
val greeting = "Hello"
val name = "World"
val json =
    """
        {
            "greeting": $greeting,
            "name": $name
        }
    """.trimIndent()
```

[Search for `raw string` in official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html)